# Removing welcome message and breadcrumbs stops the title tag appearing on category page

Tags: magento2, blocks, meta-title

I have the following lines of code in my Magento 2 template's Magento_Theme default.xml file:

```
<referenceBlock name="header" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true"/>
```

Either of these lines work correctly alone - the first to remove the welcome message, and the second to remove the breadcrumbs.

However, on the category page, the title then just renders as `<title></title>`.  Removing *either* of these lines of code makes it work fine, ie  `<title>Category Title</title>`.

Any ideas what is causing this?