# Change Welcome Message Full Name to First Name

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to change the welcome message from full name to first name here is my code.

```
        <span data-bind="text: customer().fullname"></span>
```

The code uses angular but I don't know how to find the custom().firstName or whatever? any idea's here?

Comment: Maybe this will be helpfull. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134092/magento-2-theme-header-welcome-message

Comment: @gx2g the welcome message uses first name by default, at least in my installation... try `customer().firstname`.

Answer (score 1):

Copy this file

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml

in your template

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[themename]/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml

change

```
customer().fullname
```

to

```
customer().firstname
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change**
In template /Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml

replace

```
customer().fullname
```

by

```
customer().firstname
```